# Perform a segue over multiple Controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue

**How is it possible to perform a segue from a UITabBarController Child ViewController to a DetailView of an UITableViewController with UINavigationController in between?**

[image]

There is a TabBarController with two childs, FirstView(Most Viewed Symbol) and NavigationController(Contacts Symbol).

The FirstView has a button, which should perform a segue to Show Profile VC.
The NavCont has a TableView with subclass All ProfilesTVC with a prototype cell as child.
AllProfilesTVC has an array with three names which are displayed by the reused cell.

**Which viewcontroller do I have to instantiate and prepare at the function prepareForSegue in FirstView (HomeVC) and where should the segue, which I create in storyboard, direct to? So that I'm at "John's" DetailView.
And is it possible that when I performed a segue to ShowProfileVC, that I can push the Back Button to return to the All ProfilesTVC?**

There is a github repo for those who want to try at [github repo](https://github.com/twofish187/SegueOverTabAndNavContr.git)

FirstView / HomeVC.swift

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // what do we do here ???
}
```

AllItemsTVC

```
class AllItemsTVC: UITableViewController {

let profiles = ["Joe", "John", "Ken"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return profiles.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    let profile = profiles[indexPath.row] as String
    cell.textLabel?.text = profile
    return cell
}

@IBAction func cancelFromShowProfile(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
}

// MARK: - Navigation

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        switch identifier {
        case "ShowProfile":
            if let showProfileVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ShowProfileVC {
                // pass the data to the destinationVC
                let selectedProfile = profiles[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row] as String
                showProfileVC.name = selectedProfile
            }
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

ShowProfileVC

```
class ShowProfileVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        textLabel.text = name
    }
}

var name = "Label"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

}

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with a segue, but that's not a problem because you can do it quite simply in code. Just give your view controllers an `identifier` in storyboard and instantiated them via this identifier with the appropriate `UIStoryboard` API.

Start by switching to the other tab bar item in code, and then first tell the navigation controller to `popToRootViewController`, after which you can push all the necessary controllers onto the navigation stack in turn. You can do all the configuration you normally do in `prepareForSegue` just before pushing the controllers.

The trick is to do it all with `animated` set to `false` except the last step.